# Multiply Two Column and initialize it into Another Column while creating MySQL Table

Tags: mysql

I want to create a MySQL table that has four column
For example, id,piece,price,totalprice

When data inserted into id,piece,price column totalprice must be initialized from (piece * price)

Insert data

```
id   piece   price
101   2       10
```

Result

```
id    piece price totalprice
101   2      10     20
```

I can create a table with four column but i can't automatically initialized into totalprice column using the piece and price column value.

How to do that?

Comment: [CREATE TABLE and Generated Columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html)

Comment: Trigger is also an option as is calculating on the insert..select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as follows :

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
  id int not null AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
  piece DOUBLE,
  price DOUBLE,
  totalPrice DOUBLE AS (piece * price)
);

INSERT INTO orders (piece, price) VALUES(1,1),(3,4),(6,8);
```

check it here : https://dbfiddle.uk/7wcEDixV